# wp_redirect() function is not going to right location based on the condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I am redirecting the user to a different location based on the data from the **options** table using `wp_logout` hook.

**So the callback function of `wp_logout` hook is bellow:** (note: I have commented out some code becuase I am testing it )

```
public function logout_redirect_to() {      
    $options = $this->load_all_options();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($options);
    echo '<hr/>';

    $user = wp_get_current_user();      

    print_r($user);
    echo '<hr/>';

    foreach ($options as $role_name => $redirect_to) {
        $role_name = strtolower($role_name);    

        print_r($role_name);            
        echo '<hr/>';

        print_r($user->roles);                      
        echo '<hr/>';

        if (in_array($role_name, $user->roles ) ) {

            print_r($redirect_to);
            echo '<hr/>';

            //wp_redirect(site_url("/".$redirect_to[0]));                   
            //exit();
        } else {
            //wp_redirect(site_url('/'));    
            //exit();
        }           
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Above condition is always go to else block that's means it's going to site home page. But you can see that I have some condtion to redirect to different page.

**What is the condtion?**

Here you can see I am gettng data from `options` table using `$options` variable and it's ouput is bellow:

```
Array
(
    [Administrator] => Array
        (
            [0] => about-us
        )

    [Editor] => Array
        (
            [0] => account
        )

    [Author] => Array
        (
            [0] => blog
        )

    [Subscriber] => Array
        (
            [0] => support
        )

    [Shop_Accountant] => Array
        (
            [0] => support
        )

    [Shop_Vendor] => Array
        (
            [0] => purchase-confirmation
        )

)
```

and I am also checking that user has that role which is exist in the `$options` variable. So the `$user` variable output is bellow:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [user_login] => umme
            [user_pass] => $P$BE0lB.YAcEqeIBJVm3QhdieaJtRrFE.
            [user_nicename] => umme
            [user_email] => umme@gmail.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2019-10-22 18:15:52
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Umme Habiba
        )

    [ID] => 3
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [shop_accountant] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => thcapabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => shop_accountant
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [read] => 1
            [edit_posts] => 
            [delete_posts] => 
            [edit_products] => 1
            [read_private_products] => 1
            [view_shop_reports] => 1
            [export_shop_reports] => 1
            [edit_shop_payments] => 1
            [shop_accountant] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
    [site_id:WP_User:private] => 1
)
```

**Now**, in the `foreach` loop I am checking that `$role_name` variable value is exist in `$user->roles` array. To do that I am using `in_array()` and Also I am checking that what is output of this both variable.

**Both variable output is:**

```
administrator
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
editor
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
author
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
subscriber
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
shop_accountant
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
Array
(
    [0] => support
)
shop_vendor
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
```

and `$redirect_to` is showing me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => about-us
)
Array
(
    [0] => account
)
Array
(
    [0] => blog
)
Array
(
    [0] => support
)
Array
(
    [0] => support
)
Array
(
    [0] => support
)
Array
(
    [0] => purchase-confirmation
)
```

**Now the main question:**

On the above output you can see that `$role_name` variable is showing me

```
shop_accountant
```

and `$user->roles` is showing me

```
Array
(
    [0] => shop_accountant
)
```

**Then**, why `in_array()` is always going to else block??

Answer (score 0):

May be I fixed it.

It was not working ebcuase of on the first loop it's return false and that's why it's going to else block to redirect to home page.

Now, I have change the code and  it's working so far...

```
if (in_array($role_name, $user->roles ) ) {
    if($redirect_to[0]) {
        wp_redirect(site_url("/".$redirect_to[0]));                 
        exit(); 
    } else {
        wp_redirect(site_url("/"));                 
        exit(); 
    }               
}
```

any improvment here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that may be wrong with your code;
**1°** you are using wp_die (); change it to exite (); or to die ();
wp_die (); is made to lock the screen and display a message, this is causing the conflict.

**2°** you are not placing the correct filter or in the correct order. see the example that I left below just readying your code

```
/**
 * TESTE
 */
class WpTeste
{

  function __construct(){
    add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, 'logout_redirect_to' ), 1 );
  }


  public function load_all_options(){
    return array(
        'Administrator' => array('about-us'),
        'Editor' => array('acco'),
        'Author' => array('blog'),
        'Subscriber' => array('support'),
        'Shop_Accountant' => array('support'),
        'Shop_Vendor' => array('purchase-'),
    );
  }

  public function logout_redirect_to() {   
      $options = $this->load_all_options();
      $user = wp_get_current_user();      


      foreach ($options as $role_name => $redirect_to) {
          $role_name = strtolower($role_name);    

          if (in_array($role_name, $user->roles ) ) {
                wp_redirect(site_url("/".$redirect_to[0]));    
                die();  
          }        
      }
  }
}

new WpTeste();
```

Comment: @creativeartbd no problem;) but it's nice to leave it as a simple code. Please mark this question as answered to exit the list of questions waiting for valid answers.